# Java 8 Lambdas and writing non-brittle code

Tags: java, lambda

Background: Learning Java 8 and really trying to embrace the new lambda expressions, and get smarter about writing code.  I follow this entire article (which does a very nice job of stepping through the process), down to the following code. All of a sudden what isn't clear is how these last two statements work.

The following method retrieves the email address from each member contained in roster who is eligible for Selective Service and then prints it:

```
processPersonsWithFunction(
    roster,
    p -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE
        && p.getAge() >= 18
        && p.getAge() <= 25,
    p -> p.getEmailAddress(),
    email -> System.out.println(email)
```

My understanding:
Roster is a List of type Person.  The lambda expression knows the type because we've setup a CheckPerson interface and a Predicate Interface.

p.getEmailAddress() calls the method getEmailAddress from Person class for each loop through the List. No clue what happens next, how does the variable email suddenly get introduced and used?!!!  Is this just magic, or is it that since there's 1 return value, we can just call the email variable anything here?

```
p -> p.getEmailAddress(),
email -> System.out.println(email)
```

here is the `processPersonsWithFunction` method:

```
public static void processPersonsWithFunction(
    List<Person> roster,
    Predicate<Person> tester,
    Function<Person, String> mapper,
    Consumer<String> block) {
    for (Person p : roster) {
        if (tester.test(p)) {
            String data = mapper.apply(p);
            block.accept(data);
        }
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: _email_ is just an identifier, it can be called anything.

Comment: Think of the part before the arrow as 'parameters to the method' (the part after the arrow)

Comment: If you understand where `p` comes from in the second and third arguments to `processPersonsWithFunction()`, then apply the same understanding to `email` in the last argument. It's just a formal parameter name, this time for the `accept(String)` method defined in the `Consumer<String>` interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `processPersonsWithFunction` method takes four parameters, a `List<Person>` representing people, a `Predicate<Person>` representing a function that can takes a single parameter and returns a `boolean`, a `Function<Person, String>` representing a function that takes one parameter of type `Person` and returns a `String` and finally a `Consumer<String>` representing a function that takes one parameter and returns nothing (void).

As for:

> how does the variable email suddenly get introduced and used?!!! Is
>   this just magic, or is it that since there's 1 return value, we can
>   just call the email variable anything here?

You can name the parameters of a lambda anything you want, it's just *another* identifier.

To expand on this, a *lambda* consist of three things.

1. parameters which you can name anything you want.
2. a block of code i.e. the behavior.
3. values for the free variables, i.e. the variables that are not parameters and not defined in the code.

In your case, the author most likely named the lambda parameter "email" because it's more readable and meaningful to other programmers. However, there's nothing preventing you from doing

```
e -> System.out.println(e)
```

just like the other lambda's passed to the method `processPersonsWithFunction` with a single letter parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The expression understands the type of email because `Function<X, Y>` has the same Y as `Consumer<Y>`. Also, as was said in comments, you can use any name instead of email.

```
public static <X, Y> void processElements(
    Iterable<X> source,
    Predicate<X> tester,
    Function <X, Y> mapper,
    Consumer<Y> block) {
    for (X p : source) {
        if (tester.test(p)) {
            Y data = mapper.apply(p);
            block.accept(data);
        }
    }
}
```